# CMake - Cannot find file

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to create my solution with using CMake. This is my first time and I started with something simple.

I made text file (CMakeLists.txt) and used it in CMake. I can "Configure" with no error but I have an error when I try to generate it:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:75 (ADD_EXECUTABLE):
  Cannot find source file:

    ./source/server/server.hpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
```

This is the path of my files:

```
\QTCP_Connection\source\server (contain server.cpp and server.hpp)
\QTCP_Connection\source\qtcp   (contain main.cpp)
\QTCP_Connection\source\libs   (contain singleton_holder.hpp and stdafx.hpp and stdafx.cpp and targetver.hpp)
```

And this is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
PROJECT(QTCP_Connection)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)

INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE} )
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUNICODE)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_PLUGIN)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_SHARED)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_DLL)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT)

SET(QT_DONT_USE_QTGUI TRUE)

SET(QTCP_PROJECT_DIR .)
SET(QTCP_QT_DIR $ENV{SEPANTA_QT_DIR})
SET(QTCP_BOOST_DIR $ENV{SEPANTA_BOOST_DIR})
SET(QTCP_PYTHON_DIR $ENV{SEPANTA_PYTHON_DIR})
SET(QTCP_XFS_DIR $ENV{XFS_DIR})
SET(QTCP_LOGGER_DIR $ENV{SEPANTA_LOGGER_DIR})

SET(DEVICE_MANAGER_IMPL_DIR device-manager)
SET(DEVICES_BASE_DIR ../../devices)
SET(DEVICES_IMPL_DIR devices)

SET(QTCP_DIR ${QTCP_PROJECT_DIR}/source/qtcp)
SET(SERVER_DIR ${QTCP_PROJECT_DIR}/source/server)
SET(LIBS_DIR ${QTCP_PROJECT_DIR}/source/libs)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    ${QTCP_PROJECT_DIR}/source
    ${QTCP_QT_DIR}/include
    ${QTCP_QT_DIR}/include/QtCore
    ${QTCP_BOOST_DIR}/include/boost-1_50
    ${QTCP_LOGGER_DIR}/include
    ${QTCP_PYTHON_DIR}/include
)

SET(QT_HEADERS
    ${SERVER_DIR}/server.hpp
)

QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_HEADERS_MOC ${QT_HEADERS} OPTIONS -DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED)

SET(QTCP_FILES
    ${QTCP_PROJECT_DIR}/source/qtcp/main.cpp
)

SET(SERVER_FILES
    ${SERVER_DIR}/server.hpp
    ${SERVER_DIR}/server.cpp
)   

SET(LIBS_FILES
    ${LIBS_DIR}/singleton_holder.hpp
    ${LIBS_DIR}/stdafx.cpp
    ${LIBS_DIR}/stdafx.hpp
    ${LIBS_DIR}/targetver.hpp
)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(
    ${QTCP_QT_DIR}/lib
    ${QTCP_BOOST_DIR}/lib
    ${QTCP_PYTHON_DIR}/libs
    ${QTCP_LOGGER_DIR}/lib
    ${QTCP_XFS_DIR}/XFS_WINCOR_4.1
    ${QTCP_XFS_DIR}/XFS_WINCOR_4.1/LIB)

SET(XFS_LIBS
    MSXFS
    xfs_conf
    SSIDLL)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(QTCP_Connection
    ${QT_HEADERS_MOC}
    ${QTCP_FILES}
    ${SERVER_FILES}
    ${LIBS_FILES}
)

source_group("moc_generated" FILES ${QT_HEADERS_MOC})

source_group("source\\qtcp"   FILES ${QTCP_FILES})
source_group("source\\server" FILES ${SERVER_FILES})
source_group("source\\libs"   FILES ${LIBS_FILES})


TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(QTCP_Connection
    #${QT_LIBRARIES}
    ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY}
    ${QT_QTNETWORK_LIBRARY}
    ${QT_QTSQL_LIBRARY}
    ${XFS_LIBS}
    debug log4cplusUD.lib
    optimized log4cplusU.lib
)

set_target_properties(QTCP_Connection PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/W2 /Zc:wchar_t-")
set_target_properties(QTCP_Connection PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line seems problematic:

```
SET(QTCP_PROJECT_DIR .)
```

The directory `.` will point to the working directory of the running cmake process and not to the directory of the CMakeLists file.

Instead you should use something like

```
SET(QTCP_PROJECT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

See the documentation on the [PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable%3aPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR) variable for details.

Note that you can use [`message`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3amessage) to do some simple printf-debugging if you are not sure what a certain variable points to:

```
message("PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR points to " ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Comment: I still have same problem even with "SET(QTCP_PROJECT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})" also print shows the correct path. PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR points to D:/Source-Code/QTCP_Connection

Comment: I used the message command to see files in directory cmake cant find but still is ok. message("SERVER_FILES points to " ${SERVER_FILES}) ------> SERVER_FILES points to D:/Source-Code/QTCP_Connection/source/server/server.hpp D:/Source-Code/QTCP_Connection/source/server/server.cpp

Comment: @MeysamHashemi Can you try deleting the `CMakeCache.txt` in your build folder and run it again. Also, the error given by CMake should look differently now. Can you give the new error message?

Comment: I deleted my CMakeLists.txt and made new one with new name and it worked with no problem. Kinda weird but thx for the tip ;)